# Try resending up to 3 times a request that had a response with an http status of 5[00]

Tags: angular

I'm trying to have an interceptor resend requests that had a server error for response.

But it resends all requests for now.

```
// Because the best Error is the one that never happens, improve the error handling
// using an HttpInterceptor to intercept all the server calls and retry them n times
// before throwing an error
const NB_RETRIES = 3;
const SERVER_ERROR = /^5.*$/;

@Injectable()
export class ErrorRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private errorCustomHandler: ErrorCustomHandler
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).retry(NB_RETRIES).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { }, (error: any) => {
            const isServerError: boolean = this.isServerError(error);
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && isServerError) {
                this.errorCustomHandler.handleError(error);
            }
        });
    }

    private isServerError(error): boolean {
        return SERVER_ERROR.test((error.status.toString()));
    }
}
```

The `isServerError` method behaves correctly and it detects the 500 errors all right. But I guess it does it too late or out of usefull context... as the above code still sends all retries whatever the status code.

I also tried using the `retryWhen` method but it then retries indefinitely

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private errorCustomHandler: ErrorCustomHandler
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).retryWhen(errors =>
            errors.switchMap(error =>
                this.isServerError(error) ? Observable.of(true) : Observable.throw(error)
            )
        );
    }

    private isServerError(error): boolean {
        return SERVER_ERROR.test((error.status.toString()));
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I got the retry working with the following implementation, but it then swallows my original error message

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors.switchMap(error => {
            if (this.isServerError(error)) {
                return Observable.of(error).delay(200);
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        })
        .take(NB_RETRIES)
        .concat(Observable.throw({error: 'There was a server error (after ' + NB_RETRIES + ' retries)'}));
    });
}
```

The browser console shows

```
{message: "[object Object]", method: null, name: null, appId: "My API id", user: "", …}
message:"[object Object]"
stack:{error: "There was a server error (after 3 retries)"}
url:"/login"
```

It should also show the original message

```
Cannot read property '0' of null
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the interceptor?

Comment: Guess the issue is that you don't have an exit condition. Try piping the retry and the errorhandler together as described here: https://angular.io/guide/http#retry

Comment: @VinodBhavnani What alternative do you have in mind ? Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @Stephane my bad, I misunderstood the question in my first read. But I hope my answer helps

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I had written before RXJS 6 to retry 5 times when a server error occurs.
You can possibly modify it for your use.

Shows use of retryWhen and delay, but on the older version of rxjs.

```
return this.serviceName.methodName(request)
    .retryWhen(error => {
      let retries = 0;
      return error
      .flatMap((error: any) => {
          if (retries++ < 5 && error.header.statuscode  === '501') {
            return Observable.of(error).delay(200)
          }
          return Observable.throw(error);
        })
     })
```

Probably this helps

Answer (score 0):

I write handle for each http request, you can simply loging and resend request. this is my working code:

```
return this.http.get<Candlestick[]>(pivotUrl).pipe(map(resp => {
            //console.log(resp[this.selected_serv.getselectedpair().symbol]);
            return resp[this.selected_serv.getselectedpair().symbol];
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPivot', [])
        ));
```

and handle

```
    private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      //this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
```

I hope it help you!

Comment: Thanks guys but SO is no pastebin. I'd rather have an explanation or some source code statements than copy pasted source code.